# How can I pin a PqQt label to the top without it getting resized?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I am Trying to pin a label to the top of my window without it getting resized.

[image: screenshot of my application]

I alredy tried `alignment=Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop`, but this results in the exact opposite of what i want:

[image: screenshot after alignment]

Comment: IIRC, you need to use a `QSpacerItem`. Call `QVBoxLayout.addStretch(0)` after you've added the first `QLabel` widget to your layout.

Comment: Also, it's in your best interest to provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It's unclear from your question what specific behaviour you actually want.